# SIGPIPE, Broken Pipe in a simple OpenSSL web server

Tags: c, https, openssl

I'm trying to write a simple web server that uses OpenSSL. I keep getting a "Broken Pipe" error. Even when I handle the error, it seems that the socket is never open to write to.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
/*
 * I created tempory certificates like this:
 *
 * openssl req -newkey rsa:1024 -x509 -keyout key.pem -out root.pem
 *
 * I compile like this:
 *
 * gcc -g -o webssl webssl.c -lssl -lcrypto
 *
 * I get this error:
 *
 * Program received signal SIGPIPE, Broken pipe.
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include "openssl/bio.h"
#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"

const char *password = "jake";
const char *KEY_FILE = "key.pem";
const char *CA_LIST = "root.pem";

const char *response = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nServer : webssl\r\n\r\n<html><head><title>Hello World!</title></head><body><h1>Hello world!</h1></body></html>";

void sigpipe_handle(int x)
{
    printf("broken pipe\n");
}


int password_cb(char *buf, int num, int rwflag, void *userdata)
{
    if(num<strlen(password)+1)
        return 0;
    strcpy(buf, password);
    return strlen(password);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SSL *ssl = NULL;
    SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL;

    int listenfd, clientfd;
    struct sockaddr_in clientaddr;
    socklen_t addrlen;
    char *port = "8080";

    struct addrinfo hints, *res;

    char buffer[5000];

    SSL_library_init();

    /* Set up a SIGPIPE handler */
    signal(SIGPIPE,sigpipe_handle);

    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_server_method());
    SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(ctx, KEY_FILE);
    SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb(ctx, password_cb);
    SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KEY_FILE, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, CA_LIST, 0);

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    getaddrinfo(NULL, port, &hints, &res);
    listenfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, 0);
    bind(listenfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    freeaddrinfo(res);

    listen(listenfd, 15);

    while (1) {
        addrlen = sizeof(clientaddr);
        clientfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr *)&clientaddr, &addrlen);

        ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
        SSL_set_fd(ssl, clientfd);
        SSL_accept(ssl);

        SSL_read(ssl, buffer, 5000);

        SSL_write(ssl, response, strlen(response));

        SSL_free(ssl);
        close(clientfd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: SIGPIPE is raised when you `send(2)` into a socket that has been closed on the other end. Pass the `MSG_NOSIGNAL` flag to suppress the signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SIGPIPE, Broken Pipe in a simple OpenSSL web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150072/)

I think I was generating the certificates wrong. I needed to use a server.pem that I make like this:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:1024 -x509 -keyout key.pem -out root.pem
cat key.pem root.pem > server.pem
```

I'm still not quite sure what the problem was but this code works:

```
/*
 * Created my new server.pem like this:
 *
 * openssl req -newkey rsa:1024 -x509 -keyout key.pem -out root.pem
 * cat key.pem root.pem > server.pem
 *
 * Compiled like this:
 * gcc -o webssl webssl.c -lssl -lcrypto
 *
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

const int PORT = 3000;
const char *CA_LIST = "root.pem";
const char *KEY_FILE = "server.pem";
const char *PASSWORD = "jake";

const char *message = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nServer: webssl\r\n\r\n<html><head><title>Hi</title></head><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>";

static int password_cb(char *buf, int num, int rwflag, void *userdata)
{
    if(num<strlen(PASSWORD)+1)
    return(0);

    strcpy(buf,PASSWORD);
    return(strlen(PASSWORD));
}

static void sigpipe_handle(int x) {}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    int sock, s;
    SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL;
    SSL *ssl = NULL;
    char buffer[5000];

    BIO *sbio = NULL;
    BIO *io = NULL;
    BIO *ssl_bio = NULL; 

    SSL_library_init();

    signal(SIGPIPE, sigpipe_handle);

    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_method());
    SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(ctx, KEY_FILE);
    SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb(ctx, password_cb);
    SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KEY_FILE, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, CA_LIST, 0);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
    listen(sock, 5);

    while (1) {
        memset(buffer, 0, 5000);

        s = accept(sock, 0, 0);

        sbio=BIO_new_socket(s,BIO_NOCLOSE);
        ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
        SSL_set_bio(ssl,sbio,sbio);


        SSL_accept(ssl);

        io=BIO_new(BIO_f_buffer());
        ssl_bio=BIO_new(BIO_f_ssl());
        BIO_set_ssl(ssl_bio,ssl,BIO_CLOSE);
        BIO_push(io,ssl_bio);


        BIO_gets(io, buffer, 5000);

        BIO_puts(io, message);
        BIO_flush(io);

        SSL_shutdown(ssl);
        SSL_free(ssl);
        close(s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)`. This should make send to return EPIPE error. Otherwise you can follow [Kerrek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb)'s suggestion in the comment of sending a MSG_NOSIGNAL flag to the send call.