# Cannot read cert-file with boost asio ssl use_certificate_chain_file

Tags: c++, openssl, boost-asio

I've  built a websocket-ssl, but when I use  use_certificate_chain_file function to load a cert-file, it said "ec = asio.ssl:33558560, msg = Broken pipe".

It work until yesterday, and I haven't changed the cert-file.

```
ctx_->use_certificate_chain_file(certFile, ec);
if (ec)
{
    LOG_ERR << "use_certificate_chain_file failed, ec = " << ec << ", msg = " << ec.message();
}

boost::system::error_code ec1;
ctx_->use_rsa_private_key_file(keyFile, boost::asio::ssl::context::pem, ec1);
if (ec1)
{
    LOG_ERR << "use_private_key_file failed, ec = " << ec1 << ", msg = " << ec.message();
    return;
}
```

Why this error occurs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150072/sigpipe-broken-pipe-in-a-simple-openssl-web-server

Comment: FYI, it has nothing to do with Asio, `use_certificate_chain_file` just wraps `::SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(...)` call

Comment: @Explorer_N The certfile was named as A.crt,  it works until yesterday. Bur not works today. And I change its name to A.pem, it works!! So confused, why it works yesterday